# Server side of a chat program - part 2

Tags: java, beginner, server, static, chat

A few days ago I posted a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148393/server-side-of-a-chat-program/148397?noredirect=1#comment279325_148397) about my code. It was obviously awful and thanks to some advice from [Hosch250](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34073/hosch250) I learnt a lot of things about OOP.

Now, I rewrote the program. To me it seems a little bit better than the previous one but I still feel that something is wrong.

In ServerSide.java there are 2 threads: one accepts new clients, and the other listens for messages from the clients. Since the second thread starts only after the first thread creates a `Client`, I don't know why I should synchronize them. Both of the classes share a static list so I don't see the point to use synchronization.

I would like to avoid using the methods `userClicksSubmit(String messages)` and `appendMessage(String text)` as static, but I don't know how to.

**ServerSide.java**

```
public class ServerSide extends Thread {
private ServerSocket ss;
private Socket sock;
private int ID;
private static Map<Client, Integer> clientList = new HashMap<Client, Integer>();
private static PrintWriter pw;
int port;

// Main Constructor takes the port to connect to a server
// in order to chat with the clients
public ServerSide(int port) throws IOException {
    this.port = port;
    this.run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    receivingClients();
}

public void receivingClients() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            sock = ss.accept();
            clientList.put(new Client(sock, ID), ID);
            ID++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//Static method that is called every time the server's user submits a message
public static void userClicksSubmit(String messages) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<Client, Integer> client : clientList.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(messages);
        pw = new PrintWriter(client.getKey().getSock2().getOutputStream());
        pw.println(messages);
        pw.flush();
    }
}
   //////////////////////////// Receives the clients' messages ////////////////////////////
private class Client extends Thread{

    private InputStreamReader inReader;
    private BufferedReader buffReader;
    private Socket sock2;
    private PrintWriter pw2;
    private int ID;
    private String messages;

    public Client(Socket sock2, int ID) throws IOException {
        this.sock2 = sock2;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.start();
    }
    public void getMessages() throws IOException {
        inReader = new InputStreamReader(sock2.getInputStream());
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

        while ((messages = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Static method of the Graphic Interface.It appends the messages to the textArea of the application
            GraphicSide.appendMessage(messages);
            //Send the received messages to all the clients of the map list with the exception of the sender
            for (Map.Entry<Client, Integer> client : clientList.entrySet()) {
                pw2 = new PrintWriter(client.getKey().getSock2().getOutputStream());
                if (client.getValue() != ID) {
                    pw2.println(messages);
                    pw2.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Socket getSock2() {
        return sock2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getMessages();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 }

}
```

**GraphicSide.java**

```
public class GraphicSide extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private static JTextField textPort;
private JTextField textId;
private JButton submit;
private int port;
private static JTextArea textArea;
private static boolean agree = false;
private  String text;
private String id;


public GraphicSide() {
    setTitle("Login of the Server");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBounds(100, 100, 250, 355);
    setVisible(true);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JLabel portName = new JLabel("Port:");
    portName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    portName.setBounds(106, 102, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(portName);

    textPort = new JTextField();
    textPort.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textPort.setToolTipText("e.g. 81");
    textPort.setBounds(77, 127, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(textPort);
    textPort.setColumns(10);

    JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Id:");
    idLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    idLabel.setBounds(106, 174, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(idLabel);

    textId = new JTextField();
    textId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textId.setToolTipText("e.g. Mike");
    textId.setBounds(77, 199, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(textId);
    textId.setColumns(10);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (textId.getText().length() == 0 || textPort.getText().length() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Compile all the fields", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            setVisible(false);
            try {
                id = textId.getText();
                new ChatWindow();
                agree = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    submit.setBounds(94, 257, 74, 23);
    contentPane.add(submit);

}

private class ChatWindow extends JFrame {
    {
        this.setTitle("Server");
        this.setSize(750, 480);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 480));

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout_1.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 640, 70 };
        gridBagLayout_1.rowHeights = new int[] { 387, 0, 0, 41, 40 };
        gridBagLayout_1.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 };
        gridBagLayout_1.rowWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout_1);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        DefaultCaret caret = new DefaultCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 2);
        gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textArea.gridy = 0;
        this.getContentPane().add(scroll, gbc_textArea);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea_1.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_textArea_1.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_textArea_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea_1.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 5);
        gbc_textArea_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textArea_1.gridy = 3;
        this.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textArea_1);
        this.setVisible(true);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                text = textField.getText();
                try {
                    ServerSide.userClicksSubmit(textId.getText()+" : " +text);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                textArea.append(text + '\n');
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "enter");
        AbstractAction pressedAction = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Here you put the code that is run when you press the key
                btnNewButton.doClick();
                System.out.println("Key pessed");

            }

        };
        textField.getActionMap().put("enter", pressedAction);

        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 4;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

    }
}
public static void appendMessage(String text) {
    textArea.append(text + '\n');
}

public  boolean isAgree() {
    return agree;
}

public  int getPort() {
    return port = Integer.parseInt(textPort.getText());
}

}
```

**MainClass.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClassApp extends JFrame {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    GraphicSide gs = new GraphicSide();
    //Starts the server class only after the user inserts a port and presses the submit button on the GUI 
    //application
    while (true) {
        if (gs.isAgree() == true) {
            break;
        }
    }
    new ServerSide(gs.getPort());
  }
}
```

Comment: I could create a GraphicSide object and call it from the ServerSide class,inside its thread instead of calling it in the main class.Doing that would allows me to get rid of static in " appendMessage(String text) ".
But how can i get rid of static in " userClicksSubmit(String messages) " ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few correction.In order to delete static from the 2 methods,i created a GraphicSide object diretly in the ServerSide class and built a method on the GraphicSide class that contains a ServerSide object.I also removed the HashMap and changed it in an ArrayList.Should i change something else?
What do you think about this new code?

ServerSide.java

```
public class ServerSide extends Thread {
private ServerSocket ss;
private Socket sock;
private int ID;
private static ArrayList<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
private static PrintWriter pw;
int port;
private GraphicSide gs;

// Main Constructor 
public  ServerSide() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     gs = new GraphicSide();
    // Starts the Thread  only after the user inserts a port and presses the submit button on the GUI
    // application
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if (gs.isAgree()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Passes the current ServerSide object to the GraphicSideClass
    gs.setServerSide(this);
    this.run();

}

@Override
public void  run() {
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(gs.getPort());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    receivingClients();
}

public void receivingClients() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            sock = ss.accept();
            clientList.add(new Client(sock, ID));
            ID++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Method that is called every time the server's user submits a
// message
public void userClicksSubmit(String messages) throws IOException {
    for (Client client : clientList) {
        System.out.println(messages);
        pw = new PrintWriter(client.getSock2().getOutputStream());
        pw.println(messages);
        pw.flush();
    }
}

//////////////////////////// Receives the clients' messages ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private class Client  {

    private InputStreamReader inReader;
    private BufferedReader buffReader;
    private Socket sock2;
    private PrintWriter pw2;
    private int ID;
    private String messages;

    public Client(Socket sock1, int ID) throws IOException {
        this.sock2 = sock1;
        this.ID = ID;
        t1.start();
    }

    public void getMessages() throws IOException {
        inReader = new InputStreamReader(sock2.getInputStream());
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

        while ((messages = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Method of the Graphic Interface.It appends the
            // messages to the textArea of the application
            gs.appendMessage(messages);
            // Sends the received messages to all the clients of the          Arraylist
            // with the exception of the sender
            for (Client client : clientList) {
                pw2 = new PrintWriter(client.getSock2().getOutputStream());
                if (ID != client.getID()) {
                    pw2.println(messages);
                    pw2.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Socket getSock2() {
        return sock2;
    }
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getMessages();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }       
 }
}
```

GraphicSide.java

```
public class GraphicSide extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private static JTextField textPort;
private JTextField textId;
private JButton submit;
private int port;
private static JTextArea textArea;
private static boolean agree = false;
private  String text;
private String id;
private ServerSide ss;


public GraphicSide() {
    setTitle("Login of the Server");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBounds(100, 100, 250, 355);
    setVisible(true);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JLabel portName = new JLabel("Port:");
    portName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    portName.setBounds(106, 102, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(portName);

    textPort = new JTextField();
    textPort.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textPort.setToolTipText("e.g. 81");
    textPort.setBounds(77, 127, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(textPort);
    textPort.setColumns(10);

    JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Id:");
    idLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    idLabel.setBounds(106, 174, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(idLabel);

    textId = new JTextField();
    textId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textId.setToolTipText("e.g. Mike");
    textId.setBounds(77, 199, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(textId);
    textId.setColumns(10);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (textId.getText().isEmpty()  || textPort.getText().isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Compile all the fields", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            setVisible(false);
            try {
                id = textId.getText();
                new ChatWindow();
                agree = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    submit.setBounds(94, 257, 74, 23);
    contentPane.add(submit);

}

private class ChatWindow extends JFrame {
    {
        this.setTitle("Server");
        this.setSize(750, 480);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 480));

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout_1.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 640, 70 };
        gridBagLayout_1.rowHeights = new int[] { 387, 0, 0, 41, 40 };
        gridBagLayout_1.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 };
        gridBagLayout_1.rowWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout_1);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        DefaultCaret caret = new DefaultCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 5, 2);
        gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textArea.gridy = 0;
        this.getContentPane().add(scroll, gbc_textArea);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea_1.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_textArea_1.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_textArea_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea_1.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 5);
        gbc_textArea_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textArea_1.gridy = 3;
        this.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textArea_1);
        this.setVisible(true);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                text = textField.getText();
                try {
                    setServerSide(ss);
                    System.out.println(ss);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                textArea.append(text + '\n');
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "enter");
        AbstractAction pressedAction = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                btnNewButton.doClick();
                System.out.println("Key pessed");

            }

        };
        textField.getActionMap().put("enter", pressedAction);

        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 4;
        this.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

    }
}
public void appendMessage(String text) {
    textArea.append(text + '\n');
 }

public  boolean isAgree() {
    return agree;
 }

public  int getPort() {
    return port = Integer.parseInt(textPort.getText());
 }
public void setServerSide(ServerSide ss) throws IOException {
    this.ss = ss;
    ss.userClicksSubmit(textId.getText()+" : " +text);

 }
}
```

MainClassApp.java

```
public class MainClassApp extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    new ServerSide();

 }
}
```